# Аннотация, которая не дает собрать release

Tags: android, android-studio

Я встречал упоминание какой-то метки, возможно, аннотации, которая не дает собрать release. Используется для того, чтобы не забыть исправить нужные места в коде.

Подскажите, что это и как включить?

Comment: А точно есть аннотация? По моему можно делать чтобы если lint нашел ошибки какие-то, то не собирать проект

Comment: @pavel163 я нашел. это делается lint'ом, см. ответ ниже.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Настройте Android Studio падать при сборке, если код содержит `//STOPSHIP`.
Чтобы включить в lint проверку на `//STOPSHIP`, добавьте в ваш `build.gradle`

```
android {
    ...
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError true
        fatal 'StopShip'
    }
}
```

Если у вас есть //STOPSHIP комментарий в коде, релизная сборка не соберётся. Кроме этого, вы также можете включить в Android Studio подсветку таких комментариев (по умолчанию выключено). Preferences → Editor → Code Style → Inspections. Ищите в поиске STOPSHIP и устанавливайте флажок для подсветки.

Источник: https://habrahabr.ru/post/319562/

Comment: Век живи - век учись! Слышал бы ты стук моей выпавшей челюсти :)

Comment: Еще вариант подсказали: https://github.com/Stuie/papercut